Remap the arrow key in VSCode's problem panel
I want to remap hjkl to the arrow key in VSCode's problems panel, but I couldn't figure out the way. I've tried mapping list.focusUp and list.focusDown, but it doesn't seem to work in the problems panel.
Related: VS Code - Remap certain arrow key functionality

What you saw (and I see it too) is odd.  It seems that list commands should work, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20440 where Problems have adopted the list focus commands...
In any case, it is always wise to try a more restrictive when clause first.
This works for me - I assume you have the focus in the Problems view already:
{
  "key": "k",
  "command": "list.focusUp",
  "when": "workbench.panel.markers.view.active"
  //  "when": "focusedView == 'workbench.panel.markers.view'"  // or this
},

{
  "key": "j",
  "command": "list.focusDown",
  "when": "workbench.panel.markers.view.active"
  //  "when": "focusedView == 'workbench.panel.markers.view'"  // or this
}

I don't know what you want the left/right to do in the Problems though.

I see you have filed a GitHub issue: 
Bind directional hjkl for the Problems panel.
Fixed, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/211297#issuecomment-2078288583.  Which I can confirm is now working in the Insiders Build as of 04/26/2025.  So this now works:
 {
  "key": "k",
  "command": "list.focusUp",
  "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus && !treestickyScrollFocused",
},

{
  "key": "j",
  "command": "list.focusDown",
  "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus && !treestickyScrollFocused",
}

as well as the keybindings I previously suggested using a when clause such as workbench.panel.markers.view.active which is probably the better practice since it is more specific to the use case.

@user See the edited answer - I don't know why the list focus commands do not work.

Thank you, workbench.panel.markers.view.active interferes with the Vim plugin, but focusedView == 'workbench.panel.markers.view' works perfectly for me!

Actually another thing:  for hl keys I'm using it for list.expand and list.collapse. But for some reason the commands forces the filter box to be focused, is there any workarounds to this?

I managed a workaround by running widgetNavigation.focusNext afterwards with runCommands, but I'm not sure if this is robust. Does workbench.panel.markers always refers to the Problems panel?

I used the default when clause- listFocus && !inputFocus && !treestickyScrollFocused, which had the issue of the filter getting focus for typing when key had no modifiers. The asker raised an issue ticket at Bind directional hjkl for the Problems panel #211297, and the maintainers responded with this change, which prevents focusing the filter if soft-dispatching the keyboard event finds that more chords are needed to resolve potential keybindings, or if a matching keybinding is found. I.e. I think the following should work in the April 2024 release of VS Code (1.89):
{
  "key": "k",
  "command": "list.focusUp",
  "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus && !treestickyScrollFocused",
},

{
  "key": "j",
  "command": "list.focusDown",
  "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus && !treestickyScrollFocused",
}

